# Setting properly aligned axis labels on matplotlib pcolor plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a simple matplotlib pcolor plot which can be reproduced with the following MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

test_data = np.array([[-0.00842278, -0.03332517, -0.01478557, -0.00275494],
       [ 0.16338327,  0.08383871,  0.03093892,  0.03380778],
       [-0.02246485, -0.1490697 , -0.14918824, -0.12745594],
       [ 0.02477743,  0.1537171 ,  0.13111042,  0.11950057],
       [-0.15408288, -0.04697411, -0.0068787 , -0.01576426],
       [ 0.03508095,  0.19434805,  0.13647802,  0.11276903],
       [-0.16683297,  0.05313956,  0.0283734 ,  0.01179509],
       [-0.08839198, -0.02095752, -0.00573671,  0.00360559],
       [ 0.15476156, -0.06324123, -0.04798161, -0.03844384],
       [-0.056892  , -0.09804484, -0.09506561, -0.08506755],
       [ 0.2318552 , -0.02209629, -0.04530164, -0.02950514],
       [-0.11914883,  0.00965362, -0.02431899, -0.0203009 ],
       [ 0.16025558,  0.02234824, -0.01480751, -0.01487853],
       [ 0.17345419, -0.04348332, -0.07625766, -0.05771962]])

test_df = pd.DataFrame(1 - abs(test_data))
test_df.columns = ['3', '6', '9', '12']
test_df.index = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30']
plt.pcolor(test_df, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlGn, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

Which produces this:

[image: plot without aligned axis labels]

As can be seen by the above the axis labels aren't correct nor are they aligned correctly with the coloured rectangles of the plot.

I can somewhat create the intended axis labelling on the x axis using the following code:

```
ax = plt.gca()
labels = [u'', u'3', u'', u'6', u'', u'9', u'', u'12', u'']
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Which produces this:

[image: second plot corrected x axis]

My problem is that I can't reproduce this on the y axis as the labels aren't in line with the centre of the rectangles.

Is there a way of making the x and y axis labels correct as stated in the dataframe titles and index? Whilst ensuring the labels are centred on the rectangles, not on the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution that I think is more straightforward, using `sns`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib # magic command for sns to use matplotlib

test_data = np.array([[-0.00842278, -0.03332517, -0.01478557, -0.00275494],
       [ 0.16338327,  0.08383871,  0.03093892,  0.03380778],
       [-0.02246485, -0.1490697 , -0.14918824, -0.12745594],
       [ 0.02477743,  0.1537171 ,  0.13111042,  0.11950057],
       [-0.15408288, -0.04697411, -0.0068787 , -0.01576426],
       [ 0.03508095,  0.19434805,  0.13647802,  0.11276903],
       [-0.16683297,  0.05313956,  0.0283734 ,  0.01179509],
       [-0.08839198, -0.02095752, -0.00573671,  0.00360559],
       [ 0.15476156, -0.06324123, -0.04798161, -0.03844384],
       [-0.056892  , -0.09804484, -0.09506561, -0.08506755],
       [ 0.2318552 , -0.02209629, -0.04530164, -0.02950514],
       [-0.11914883,  0.00965362, -0.02431899, -0.0203009 ],
       [ 0.16025558,  0.02234824, -0.01480751, -0.01487853],
       [ 0.17345419, -0.04348332, -0.07625766, -0.05771962]])


Cols = ['3', '6', '9', '12']
Index = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30']
test_df = pd.DataFrame(1 - abs(test_data),index=Index, columns=Cols)
sns.heatmap(test_df,cmap=plt.cm.RdYlGn,vmin=0,vmax=1,cbar=True)
```

As you will notice, it plot the exact same thing, but directly use index and columns as labels.

Another difference is that it uses the original indexes of the `DataFrame`, so your graph is not upside-down like with the matplotlib solution.

Note that on my computer, I have to enlarge the window to see the colorbar, otherwise it is hidden.

Answer (score 4):

Its not great to do it like this (you are decoupling the tick labels from the data), but you can do this:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pcolor(test_df, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlGn, vmin=0, vmax=1)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(test_df.index))+0.5)
ax.set_yticklabels(test_df.index)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(test_df.columns))+0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(test_df.columns)
```

We are setting the ticks to every `0.5, 1.5, 2.5` (to centre them), etc., and then setting the tick labels from your `dataframe` index and columns.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, to extend my question - do you know how I would set a colour bar legend for this example?

Comment: @BML91 you can just add `plt.colorbar()` before `plt.show`. Note that the range of the colorbar is defined by your `vmin` and `vmax` arg in the `pcolor`